# Initiate websocket from server behind router

Tags: websocket, server, webrtc

I have a local webserver behind a router and can't portforward any port on the router.

Is it possible to start a connection from a browser outside the local network to the server behind the router? Maybe it's possible with a cloud-server to initiate the connection between the two?

[image]

Comment: Although you can not establish a client server connection between a browser and your local server, you can implement a work-around:
You can have both your *local server* acting as web socket clients (or any other messaging clients):


 - Both clients connect to the cloud server (a messaging server).
 - The browser client sends a message to the *local server* client asking for data.
 - The server sends the requested data to the client

But how is your question connected to WebRTC?

Answer (score 3):

No. WebSockets use TCP and then you would need to map a port from "Router" to "Local server" in order to allow connectivity.

However, you can take a look at [WebRTC data channels](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/datachannels/).

Cheers.